# How to use mongoosastic plugin with typegoose

Tags: typescript, mongoosastic, typegoose

I am wondering how to install and use mongoosastic(`^4.6.0`) with typegoose (`@typegoose/typegoose: "^7.4.5"`). I was unable to install `@types/mongoosastic` package. So to setup the plugin I did:

```
import { prop, getModelForClass, index, plugin } from "@typegoose/typegoose";
var mongoosastic = require('mongoosastic');


@index({ location: '2dsphere' })
@plugin(mongoosastic)
export class Vehicle {
...
}

export const VehicleModel = getModelForClass(Vehicle);
```

When I save a new vehicle object using typegoose (`await VehicleModel.create({...} as Vehicle);`) the piece of data is immediately sync with elasticsearch.

The issue now is I cannot use do `Vehicle.search(...)` on the Vehicle class because the .search method is not added by the plugin as indicated in the [mongoosastic docs](https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic). How is this done??? Thank you in advance.

Comment: "The issue now is I cannot use do Vehicle.search(...) on the Vehicle class" in what way can you not? What error do you encounter?

Comment: Hello @alexandradeas I just updated the question.

Comment: When you declare the `Vehicle` class, you can add a `search` method to the definition.

Comment: @ExplosionPills that's supposed to be added by the plugin on the Vehicle class.

Comment: @cdaiga added by which plugin? Mongoostatic does add it, but it does not add the type. I'm talking about adding the type definition, not the function itself.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I don't really know how to do this, I am a newbie in typescript. Would you mind helping if you can?

Comment: @cdaiga typegoose offers an type implementation for another plugin, you can look there to see how to define type definitions on your class https://github.com/typegoose/typegoose/blob/a1fac7525f19a215a342437afe0a336656d43e41/src/defaultClasses.ts#L35-L38

Comment: Thanks @hasezoey, I have gone through the code but can't figure out how to with the code.